# probability of number of balls in a bin

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Suppose we throw 180 balls into 10 bins, choosing a random a bin independently from previous throws. What's the probability that *some bin* has k balls or more?

Comment: From computer simulation I see that there is almost always bucket with 13 balls or less and bucket with 24 balls or more. It surprised me because I would expect that number of balls in all buckets will be much closer to 18.

Comment: Not quite the same question, but the expected number of buckets with $13$ or fewer balls is about $1.294$, which you can find in R with `10*pbinom(13,180,1/10)`. Similarly the expected number of buckets with $24$ or more balls is about $0.896$.  So each event should happened reasonably often, but not *almost always*

Comment: It actually helps me. I was asking it in context of load balancing. It surprised me that for load that was uniformly splitted between 10 shards we had max/min ratio ~ 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Say you have $n=180$ balls and $m=10$ buckets.

If the probability for $j$ particular buckets to contain $k$ or more balls is $p_j$, then by inclusion–exclusion the probability for at least one bucket to contain $k$ or more balls is

$$
\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}\binom mjp_j\;.
$$

We have

$$
p_1=m^{-n}\sum_{i=k}^n\binom ni(m-1)^{n-i}\;,
$$

$$
p_2=m^{-n}\sum_{i_1=k}^n\sum_{i_2=k}^n\binom n{i_1,i_2}(m-2)^{n-i_1-i_2}\;,
$$

$$
p_3=m^{-n}\sum_{i_1=k}^n\sum_{i_2=k}^n\sum_{i_3=k}^n\binom n{i_1,i_2,i_3}(m-3)^{n-i_1-i_2-i_3}\;,
$$

and so on. For $k=24$, a case you were interested in, this yields

\begin{eqnarray*}
p_1&\approx&8.962965\cdot10^{-2}\;,\\
p_2&\approx&5.137713\cdot10^{-3}\;,\\
p_3&\approx&1.566055\cdot10^{-4}\;,\\
p_4&\approx&1.843512\cdot10^{-6}\;,\\
p_5&\approx&4.496161\cdot10^{-9}\;,\\
p_6&\approx&5.274765\cdot10^{-13}\;,\\
p_7&\approx&1.965299\cdot10^{-20}\;,\\
p_8&=&p_9=p_{10}=0\;,\\
\end{eqnarray*}

and thus the probability for at least one bucket to contain $24$ or more balls is

$$
\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}\binom mjp_j\approx0.683506\;.
$$

The exact number of favourable results out of the $10^{180}$ possible results is

```
683506088319267176075812493611972506717354414439467258046005070314955639642255566511980636893571539150511657874914743568360842020841283776523218664781531830516427726070368000000000.
```

Interestingly, my first attempt at verifying this with simulations failed and was off by about $0.001$. It turned out that this was due to regularities in Java's built-in pseudorandom number generator; the discrepancy was resolved when I used an [XOR shift generator](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/xorshift.shtml#.WzxzG35CR24) instead.

[Here's the Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/6b409b2636027e22c98c604e06f32547) for the evaluation of the sums and the simulation.

Comment: How is your computations are related to the formula below? Can I approximate them with Poisson?

Answer (score 3):

When you say "uniform distribution," I think you mean instead a Poisson distribution.  Here the expected number of balls in each bucket is $180/10 = 18$.  Here is the distribution of balls in any given bucket:

[image]

The probability that a given (single) bucket has more than $k$ such balls is:

$$\frac{\Gamma (\lfloor k\rfloor +1)-\Gamma (\lfloor k\rfloor +1,18)}{\Gamma (\lfloor k\rfloor +1)}$$

which has a form:

[image]

So the chance that a single bucket does not have more than $k$ balls is:

$$q = 1 - \frac{\Gamma (\lfloor k\rfloor +1)-\Gamma (\lfloor k\rfloor +1,18)}{\Gamma (\lfloor k\rfloor +1)}$$,

and the chance that *none* of the 10 buckets has more than $k$ is $q^{10}$, so the chance that at least one of the buckets has more than $k$ is $1 - q^{10}$.

Note that this is under the assumption that on average 180 balls are thrown, not precisely the stated assumptions.  For example, if 180 are thrown, then it is *certain* that at least one bucket will have 18 or more balls.

Comment: The events of different buckets having more than $k$ balls aren't independent, so you can't multiply them, at least not in an exact sense. They might be nearly independent for some values of $k$, but certainly not for central values.

Comment: Also, I don't understand your introductory remark "When you say "uniform distribution," I think you mean instead a Poisson distribution." I understand the OP to mean that for each ball, a bucket is uniformly randomly selected (independently, though that's not explicitly stated). You might be able to argue that a Poisson distribution in the individual buckets is a good approximation, but that's quite different from assuming that that's what the OP intended to ask about, for which I see no indication in the post.

Comment: What can "uniform distribution" mean in this case?  That each bucket is equally likely to have between $0$ and (some) $s$ balls in it, where the sum of the $10$ buckets is $180$?  This is an extremely unusual model.  (And what would $s$ be?).  If a *bucket* is randomly selected, then indeed you get a Poisson distribution... much like raindrops falling into buckets, a classic example of a Poisson.

Comment: I don't see anything unusual about it at all. I already wrote above what I think it means, and except for the fact that the independence assumption is missing and the buckets would more usually be called bins, it seems like a very standard setup. The marginal distribution for each bucket is a binomial distribution, not a Poisson distribution, and the binomial distributions for different buckets are correlated. It seems that at least one of us is seriously misinterpreting the question :-)

Comment: A *uniform distribution* of choice of bucket (bin) leads to a Poisson distribution of balls within each bin (modulo the independence assumption).  No incompatibility in understanding/assumptions.

Comment: No -- a Poisson distribution has support on all of $\mathbb N$. If we throw $180$ balls into the bins, the resulting distribution must have support on $[0,180]$. The Poisson distribution is an approximation -- which is fine, I'm not saying it might not be a good one -- I just don't understand how you can say that it actually *is* a Poisson distribution, which would potentially require an infinite number of balls. That's what we'd get if we'd throw balls in a Poisson process with a constant rate for $180$ times the time constant, but I don't see any indication that that's what the OP means.

Comment: Each bin has a distribution which is binomially distributed with parameters 180 and 0.1.  The difficult part is that the bins are not independnet

Comment: You are correct:  A true Poisson is in the limit of large number of points... with other conditions.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I meant that each ball "chooses" a bucket $[1, 10]$ with uniform distribution. I do not know what is the distribution of balls in each bucket after $n=180$  throws.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork you used $Γ(⌊k⌋+1,18)$ notation. Is it incomplete upper Gamma function as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function ?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  $Γ(25) = 6.204e+23$. Are you sure is what you meant?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork how to reformulate the formula via factorials?

Answer (score 0):

However, when it comes to labelled balls, an e.g.f. is waiting somewhere to be written.

Assume that the capacity of a bucket is 23. Then the e.g.f. for one bucket is:

$ 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{23}}{23!} $

for ten distinct buckets one will have :

$ (1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{23}}{23!})^{10} $

We are now interested in the coefficient of $\frac{x^{180}}{180!}$, which agrees with previous calculus.

316493908895554453369790961313619572009615365012907112082570161990794872355520000505402092717575252190566769024926332221764288309486803949091940966173304490507414724761824000000000

The probability not to spill something is then 0.3164934.